# Unable to access the Internet when installed within VMware player

Tags: wireless, vmware

After a lot of troubleshooting I am still unable to get Internet working on ubuntu 12.04 installed on my VMware Player.

1. I tried commenting out `dns=dnsmasq`.
2. `ifconfig` returns: eth0 and lo with the ipaddress and other information.

I don't know what is wrong. Anyone could help me or any other commands or files I should change?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below things and update:

1. What is the gateway for the internet on the host.
2. What is the vmware network adapter state and what is the type of network adapter. (It should be bridging adapter.)
3. it is the Virtual network edit which is assigning the IP to your VM or it is your ISP router?
4. take snapshots for the same and upload. So that we will be in better possition to advice you on what could be the problem and how it can be resolved.
5. if you think everything it right then traceroute to www.google.com and rout IP gateway and upload it.

Best of luck!!